# 'undefined columns selected' using 'predict' with newdata lme4

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I'm trying to use the 'predict' function on new data after running an nlmer model, and am running into issues.

The dataset I use for the model looks like so (except patient_id has an actual value, which I can't share):

```
> data
   patient_id          variable    value M_visit_time M_agesero D_intercept D_agesero
1:     SECRET                vl 4.542850     1.624658  33.16164           0   0.00000
2:     SECRET                vl 4.408664     2.010959  33.16164           0   0.00000
3:     SECRET                vl 4.493095     2.219178  33.16164           0   0.00000
4:     SECRET                vl 4.540980     2.583562  33.16164           0   0.00000
5:     SECRET                vl 2.844477     3.293151  33.16164           0   0.00000
...
```

I run the model:

```
model_formula <- "value~ModelGradient(time=M_visit_time,b0,b2,b3)~ M_agesero +
              D_intercept + D_agesero + (b0|patient_id)"

Model<- ~b0+b2*exp(-b3*time)
ModelGradient<-deriv(Model,namevec=c("b0","b2","b3"),
                    function.arg=c("time","b0","b2","b3"))

out<-do.call("nlmer", list( as.formula(model_formula),
                          data=quote(data),
                          start = c(b0=3,b2=1,b3=4),
                          control=nlmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                                               optCtrl=list(maxfun=200000))))
```

The dataset for which I'd like predictions looks like this:

```
> newdata
    patient_id          variable    value M_visit_time M_agesero D_intercept D_agesero
 1:     SECRET observed_survival 1.198478          0.0   0.00000           1  33.16164
 2:     SECRET                vl 4.542850          0.0  33.16164           0   0.00000
 3:     SECRET                vl 4.542850          0.5  33.16164           0   0.00000
 4:     SECRET                vl 4.542850          1.0  33.16164           0   0.00000
 5:     SECRET                vl 4.542850          1.5  33.16164           0   0.00000
...
```

But when I run the command

```
newdata$predicted <- predict(out, newdata=newdata)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(fr, vars) : undefined columns selected
```

Running `data$predicted <- predict(out)` works just fine, however.

Input appreciated!

Comment: this may just be a hole in the package -- development of the `nlmer` machinery is running far behind `lmer` and `glmer` ... you may end up needing to construct predictions by hand ... sorry ... (maybe worth posting an issue on this at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues ...

Comment: @BenBolker: Follow-up question. I'm trying to manually predict (on `data`, not `newdata`, so I can compare to the output from the `predict()` function), but I'm getting discrepancies.  Am I misspecifying the manual prediction if I run `data[, predicted_test:= fe[["b0"]]+b0_re + fe[["b2"]]*exp(-fe[["b3"]]*M_visit_time) + fe[["M_agesero"]]*M_agesero + fe[["D_intercept"]]*D_intercept + fe[["D_agesero"]]*D_agesero]` with `fe` equal to `fixef(out)` and `b0_re` equal to the random effect on b0?