# manually predict nlmer outputs

Tags: r, predict, lme4

Given that I can't seem to use `predict()` on a new dataset in nlmer (see [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127559/undefined-columns-selected-using-predict-with-newdata-lme4)), I'm trying to manually predict the output of an nlmer model, but something is not right.

I run the model:

```
model_formula <- "value~ModelGradient(time=M_visit_time,b0,b2,b3)~ M_agesero + 
                  D_intercept + D_agesero + (b0|patient_id)"

Model<- ~b0+b2*exp(-b3*time)
ModelGradient<-deriv(Model,namevec=c("b0","b2","b3"),
                function.arg=c("time","b0","b2","b3"))

out<-do.call("nlmer", list( as.formula(model_formula),
                      data=quote(data),
                      start = c(b0=3,b2=1,b3=4),
                      control=nlmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                                           optCtrl=list(maxfun=200000))))
```

I then merge the random effect onto my original data (calling the column `b0_re`) and save the fixed effects as `fe <- fixef(out)`:

```
> fe
   M_agesero  D_intercept    D_agesero           b0           b2           b3 
  0.005944058 -1.798036528 -0.001427386  4.405443370  0.633165740  2.961626278
```

Finally, I call two prediction methods:

```
data$predicted_auto <- predict(out)

data[, predicted_manual:= fe[["b0"]]+b0_re + fe[["b2"]]*exp(-fe[["b3"]]*M_visit_time) +
                          fe[["M_agesero"]]*M_agesero + 
                          fe[["D_intercept"]]*D_intercept + fe[["D_agesero"]]*D_agesero]
```

But the results for the two methods are not the same:

```
            variable    value      b0_re M_visit_time M_agesero D_intercept D_agesero predicted_auto predicted_manual
1:                vl 4.542850 -0.2946956     1.624658  33.16164           0   0.00000       4.312766         4.313013
2:                vl 4.408664 -0.2946956     2.010959  33.16164           0   0.00000       4.309310         4.309503
3:                vl 4.493095 -0.2946956     2.219178  33.16164           0   0.00000       4.308612         4.308748
4:                vl 4.540980 -0.2946956     2.583562  33.16164           0   0.00000       4.308100         4.308163
5:                vl 2.844477 -0.2946956     3.293151  33.16164           0   0.00000       4.307888         4.307899
6: observed_survival 1.198478 -0.2946956     0.000000   0.00000           1  33.16164       1.053172         2.898543
```

The two methods for 'vl' look pretty close, but the ones for 'observed_survival' are quite wrong.  Where am I going astray?